# How do I get the primary menu to show on the jupiter wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, menu

I made a menu and enabled the primary location, but still it's not showing. if I reload the webpage the source says that the header is empty, it's not like if the menu is hidden.

Im using the Jupiter theme.

Comment: Do you have a link to the website

Comment: Does your menu look like this: Your menu name (primary navigation)

Comment: http://silcorpindustries.com/wp/ is the link to the site. The menu indeed looks like that